# How to avoid multiple uses of the same name?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm trying to make this little project using the symfony framework, it's pretty simple, but I'm still new to it.
I have 3 entities, Classe, Student and WorkDays. class has a OneToMany relation to Student, and another OneToMany relation to schedule.
When creating a class, you can add students and WorkDays
here's my code:
Classe entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClasseRepository")
 */
class Classe
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Student", mappedBy="classe", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $Students;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\WorkDays", mappedBy="class")
     */
    private $schedule;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Students = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->schedule = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function setLabel(string $label): self
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Student[]
     */
    public function getStudents(): Collection
    {
        return $this->Students;
    }

    public function addStudent(Student $student): self
    {
        if (!$this->Students->contains($student)) {
            $this->Students[] = $student;
            $student->setClasse($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeStudent(Student $student): self
    {
        if ($this->Students->contains($student)) {
            $this->Students->removeElement($student);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($student->getClasse() === $this) {
                $student->setClasse(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|WorkDays[]
     */
    public function getSchedule(): Collection
    {
        return $this->schedule;
    }

    public function addSchedule(WorkDays $schedule): self
    {
        if (!$this->schedule->contains($schedule)) {
            $this->schedule[] = $schedule;
            $schedule->setClass($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSchedule(WorkDays $schedule): self
    {
        if ($this->schedule->contains($schedule)) {
            $this->schedule->removeElement($schedule);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($schedule->getClass() === $this) {
                $schedule->setClass(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

student entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\StudentRepository")
 */
class Student
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\classe", inversedBy="Students")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $classe;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClasse(): ?classe
    {
        return $this->classe;
    }

    public function setClasse(?classe $classe): self
    {
        $this->classe = $classe;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and WorkDays

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\WorkDaysRepository")
 */
class WorkDays
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $day;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $start;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time")
     */
    private $end;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Classe", inversedBy="schedule")
     */
    private $class;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDay(): ?string
    {
        return $this->day;
    }

    public function setDay(string $day): self
    {
        $this->day = $day;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStart(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    public function setStart(?\DateTimeInterface $start): self
    {
        $this->start = $start;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->end;
    }

    public function setEnd(\DateTimeInterface $end): self
    {
        $this->end = $end;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClass(): ?Classe
    {
        return $this->class;
    }

    public function setClass(?Classe $class): self
    {
        $this->class = $class;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

finally this is my form, I used CollectionType to include Students and workdays and I used this plugin: https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection to add as many students and workdays as I want

```
<?php

class ClasseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Label')



            ->add('Students', CollectionType::class, [
                'label'        => 'Students',
                'entry_type'   => StudentsType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype'    => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'attr'         => [
                    'class' => 'collection',
                ],
            ])

           ->add('schedule', CollectionType::class, [
            'label'        => 'schedule',
            'entry_type'   => scheduleType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype'    => true,
            'required'     => false,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'attr'         => [
                'class' => 'collection',
            ],
        ])


        ;
                $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'See my addresses',
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Classe::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

now, everything works fine, adding student in this form would also add them in their respectable table. Same thing with work days, which let's you choose the day from a Entitytype drop-down

**My problem:**
Is there any way I can avoid duplicate students names and workdays names ? same with class names ?

Comment: Be practical: There will be students with the same names, workdays names and class names. Just accept it. Assign them a student number or something else unique.

Comment: class names should be unique sadly, same goes for days since you can't have two Mondays for the same class.

Comment: OK, but it is still a valid comment for the names of students.

Comment: yeah, I agree about the names.

Comment: Sooo, any solution ?

Comment: add `unique=true` in your `ORM\Column` definition.

Comment: It works by giving me an exception, is there anyway I can get an alert or something inside the form when I click submit ? it would be more practical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set unique attribute of the properties which have to be unique just as mentioned in the comments. And you can catch any QueryException of Doctrine’s and send back appropriate error message/response to the client.